# Линковая подсеть

Tags: сеть

Для подключения клиента из адресного пространства РТКомм-Юг выделяется подсеть на 4 адреса. Это так называемая линковая подсеть.
Если клиенту требуются реальные адреса для локальной сети, NAT или других целей, то требуется заполнение формы для ее дальнейшего оформления в RIPE.

Что это за зверь такой - Линковая подсеть на 4 адреса!? Поучается что это не интернет адреса? К ним нет доступа из сети интернет? Серый IP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Если клиенту требуются реальные адреса
> для локальной сети, NAT или других
> целей, то требуется заполнение формы
> для ее дальнейшего оформления в RIPE.

В вашем вопросе уже ответ, т.к. RIPE требует от провайдеров обоснования зачем они выделяют белые адреса, отсюда и необходимость заявки от вас.
Что касается линковой подсети, то это просто подсетка с префиком /30, где 2-а адреса выделяются под сетевой и широковещательный адрес, адрес шлюза провайдера и ваш адрес. В зависимости от вашего желания это подсетка будет иметь либо белые, либо серые адреса.

Comment: "Если клиенту требуются реальные адреса для локальной сети"
А разве локальная сеть может иметь реальный интернет адрес? На то она и локальная!? (без использования NAT, хотя с полным форвардингом портов на локальный адрес, он всё равно будет локальным) И почему когда я дома подключился к интернету никакой регистрации в RIPE у меня не требовали!?